# "Univariate time series only" error when I try to use ccf for time series analysis

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to perform a time series analysis on my data set. I have two variables, one of the downsides I have is that the dates are not continuous, i.e. there are months with 4 data, months with 1 data and the date of that data varies from month to month. I found that I could use the zoo function to convert my data set to time series to be able to apply a cross correlation. However, when I convert it to zoo, they are stored as a variable and not as data. I also tried with regular ts, but I get an error when I try to run the correlation.

[image]

The data:

structure(list(`Fecha prod Internodo` = structure(c(967221472.75,
962788545.499, 958355618.249, 953922690.999, 949489763.748, 945056836.498,
940623909.248, 936190981.998, 931758054.747, 927325127.497, 922892200.247,
918459272.996, 914026345.746, 909593418.496, 905160491.245, 900727563.995
class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Tamaño internodo sin tendencia` = c(-0.315142936666672,
-0.315973509717394, -0.303983287254609, -0.300810842569604, -0.290796220815116,
-0.291608407715995, -0.285150663885691, -0.272603176465643, -0.249304079186679,
-0.231648899458939, -0.224855258192737, -0.217679237836851, -0.219767182313487

The code looks like this

```
a= growthSpain_Cabrera_Es_Castell_5m[c("Fecha prod Internodo", "Tamaño internodo sin tendencia")]
b= growthSpain_Cabrera_Es_Castell_5m[c("Fecha", "Energia")]
a_zoo<-as.zoo(a)
b_zoo<-as.zoo(b)

library(stats)
ccf(a_zoo, b_zoo)
```

Then I get: univariate time series only

The same happens if I try with ts instead of zoo.

I just need to have two sets of data like the one in the image, as time series to be able to run a cross correlation.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, using `dput()` output, instead of a screenshot.

Comment: If you include background info and reformulate as more of a stats Q, this could be better on Cross Validated. Maybe you need methods for unevenly sampled time series